# How do I get two DIV's text, so that it becomes a table using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I iterate through the links, then access their pages' specific `divs`' content and form like a table, using Python?

I've come this far (only), but the output is not right:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
base_url = 'http://www.warrencountyschools.org'
url = 'https://www.warrencountyschools.org/district_staff.aspx?action=search&location=29&department=0'
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)

# the second tr in the table - index starts at 0
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'content staff-table'})
rows = table.findAll('tr')

fieldContent = []

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    if len(cols) >= 3:
        link = cols[2].find('a').get('href')
        abs_link = base_url+link

        profileURL = abs_link
        profilePagResp = http.request('GET', profileURL)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(profilePagResp.data)

        flDiv = soup2.findAll('div', {'class', 'field-label'})
        fcDiv = soup2.find('div', {'class', 'field-content'})
        for fl in flDiv:
            fieldContent.append(fcDiv.text)

print(fieldContent)
```

The output now consists of each name repeated the number of times it's iterates, while it should be like this:

| Name | Email | Website | Phone | Buildings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SomeName | email@ | wwww. | 78978978 | SomeBuildin |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an async library like `trio` as this is more I/0 bound as you will be awaiting responses for requests to individual staff pages. I have added a custom sort, based on last name, in attempt to recreate the original results order. For larger result sets this might not match perfectly in case of ties. You might then extend by adding in a first name sort. The additional sort column can be dropped.

There does seem to be a [FIFO processing instruction](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-lowlevel.html?highlight=order#trio.lowlevel.TrioToken.run_sync_soon) within `trio` but I haven't explored that.

```
import pandas as pd
import httpx
import trio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LINK = 'https://www.warrencountyschools.org/district_staff.aspx?action=search&location=29&department=0'
ALL_INFO = []
  
async def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')


async def get_staff_info(link, nurse):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
        r = await client.get(link)
        soup = await get_soup(r.text)
        info_items = ['Name', 'Email', 'Website', 'Phone', 'Buildings']
        staff_info = {}
        for key in info_items:
            try:
                if key == 'Website':
                    value = 'https://www.warrencountyschools.org' + soup.select_one(
                        f'.field-label:-soup-contains("{key}:") + .field-content > a')['href']
                else:
                    value = soup.select_one(
                        f'.field-label:-soup-contains("{key}:") + .field-content').text.strip()
            except:
                value = 'N/A'
            finally:
                staff_info[key.lower()] = value
        ALL_INFO.append(staff_info)


async def get_links(LINK, nurse):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
        r = await client.get(LINK)
        soup = await get_soup(r.text)
        for x in soup.select('#ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_ContentColumnRight_ctl01_dg_staff .staff-profile-button > a'):
            nurse.start_soon(
                get_staff_info, 'https://www.warrencountyschools.org' + x['href'], nurse)


async def main():
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        nurse.start_soon(get_links, LINK, nurse)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    trio.run(main)
    df = pd.DataFrame(ALL_INFO)
    df['sort_value'] = [i.strip().split(' ')[-1] for i in df['name'].tolist()]
    df.sort_values(by=['sort_value'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
    #print(df)
    df.to_csv('staff.csv',
              encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

---

Output csv:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the ellaborated way, but this is only returning ```N/A```. I tied tweaking it a bit, but without success.

Comment: How you running this? I just re-ran it and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm running it on VS Code.

Comment: Don't know. Runs fine for me no problems at all. I'm guessing you get no error codes?

Comment: Just ran it on Google Colab and it returned the same result: The headers and N/A for all fields. No errors reported!

Comment: Cool approache, selecting part looks like my inital one, but I decided to get all of the information and filter later in `pandas` - Upvoted, but sombody here is downvoting a lot today, that is a pity.   DEBUGGING INFO: Also tested with same result - You can fix it by simple change the urls from `http` to `https`. While printing some things I got following message: `Object moved to <a href="https://www.warrencountyschools.org:443/staff/25880">here</a>`

Comment: Thanks @HedgeHog. Appreciate your input. I don't see this `Object moved to`. I literally get the results as requested by OP and seen on the webpage. Otherwise, wouldn't have posted as answer. Sigh ;-(

Answer (score 1):

@Antonio Santos, All profile data aren't in the same order. So you can grab data only as follows :

#### Script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

base_url = 'http://www.warrencountyschools.org'
url = 'https://www.warrencountyschools.org/district_staff.aspx?action=search&location=29&department=0'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')

# the second tr in the table - index starts at 0
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'content staff-table'})
rows = table.findAll('tr')

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    if len(cols) >= 3:
        link = cols[2].find('a').get('href')
        abs_link = base_url+link
        print(abs_link)
        
        final_page = requests.get(abs_link)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(final_page .text,'html.parser')

        profile_data =[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup2.findAll("div","field-content")]
        
        print(profile_data)
```

## Output:

```
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13650
['Greg Blewett', 'Greg.blewett@warren.kyschools.us', 'Access Staff Website', '270-746-7205', 'Greg Blewett - Construction-Carpentry - Warren County Area Technology Center']http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25689
['Adrian Boggess', 'Staff', 'adrian.boggess@warren.kyschools.us', 'Tike Barton - Computerized Manufacturing and Machining - Warren County Area Technology Center']
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/2403
['Kim Coomer', 'Teacher', 'kim.coomer@warren.kyschools.us', '270-746-7205', 'Kim Coomer - Career Specialist - Warren County Area Technology Center']
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13651
['Rex Cundiff', 'Rex.cundiff@warren.kyschools.us', 'Access Staff Website', '270-746-7205', 'Rex Cundiff - Welding - Warren County Area Technology Center']
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13652
['Susan Devore', 'Susan.devore@warren.kyschools.us', 'Access Staff Website', '270-746-7205', 'Susan Devore - Information Technology - Warren County Area Technology Center']http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13666
['Michael Emberton', 'michael.emberton@warren.kyschools.us', 'Access Staff Website', 'Micheal Emberton - Automotive - Warren County Area Technology Center']
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25684
['Jacob Hildebrant', 'Staff', 'jacob.hildebrant@warren.kyschools.us', 'Greg Blewett - 
Construction-Carpentry - Warren County Area Technology Center']
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25346
['Jeton Hyseni', 'Staff', 'Jeton.Hyseni@warren.kyschools.us', 'Administrative Assistant - Warren County Area Technology Center']
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25041
['Jesse Muse', 'Staff', 'jesse.muse@warren.kyschools.us', 'Tike Barton - Computerized 
Manufacturing and Machining - Warren County Area Technology Center']
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/2560
['Chris Riggs', 'Staff', 'chris.riggs@warren.kyschools.us', '467-7500', 'Administrative Assistant - Warren County Area Technology Center']
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24757
['Allison Runner', 'Staff', 'allison.runner@warren.kyschools.us', 'Administrative Assistant - Warren County Area Technology Center']
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25881
['Jacob Thomas', 'Staff', 'jacob.thomas@warren.kyschools.us', 'Greg Blewett - Construction-Carpentry - Warren County Area Technology Center']
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25880
['Brooke Weakly', 'Staff', 'brooke.bruington@warren.kyschools.us', 'Administrative Assistant - Warren County Area Technology Center']
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for this. However, ```Access Staff Website``` should return a link and since some of the employees don't have all the fields, the result is coming in with results in wrong columns.

Comment: Could you please check the 1st 2 lines of the output? The 1st one doesn't have Staff and the email comes after the name. Then the 2nd, does. When I generate  a csv out of it, it'll come out of order. While I'm writing it, I'm doing my best to find out how to solve it, but too limited knowledge on it still. Thank you!

Comment: According to the url the output is correct, so far . See each url and each item

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get two DIV's text, so that it becomes a table ...

Your approach to collecting the data is already very good, but to form key value pairs, which can be transferred into a table via `pandas`, for example, we have to consider the following points:

##### Prepare the headers

Extracting the text we use a `list comprehension` and remove the colons via `list slicing` to get clean results.

```
    keys = [x.text[:-1] for x in soup2.find_all('div', {'class', 'field-label'})]
```

**Note**: *Since 2016 in `BeautifulSoup` the method `findALL()` was renamed to `find_all()` it would be better to use in new code the actually syntax.*

##### Prepare the content and glue it togehter

Extract the contents in the same way as the headers and combine them into a `dict` via `zip()`.

```
    profile = dict(tuple(zip(keys,[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup2.find_all('div', {'class', 'field-content'})])))
```

**Note** *This is the crucial point in order to be able to map the contents in the correct columns.*

##### Adjsutments on website value

Since the `url` of the website is not human-readable text (*won't get it with `text` or `get_text()` method*), but is in the `href` of the `<a>`, we have to do a separate check and take the `url` if it exists.

```
    if (website := soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Access Staff Website")')):
        profile['Website'] = base_url+website['href']
    else:
        profile['Website'] = ''
```

##### Store profiles and create the table

Last but not least, we add the `dict` to our result list and can transfer it via `pandas` into a data frame. Using `fillna()` we can determine what should be in all empty cells and `to_csv()` saves the data frame as a csv file.

```
    fieldContent.append(profile)

pd.DataFrame(fieldContent).fillna('')#.to_csv('profile.csv', index=False)
```

**Note** *In `pandas` you can determine which columns should be in output, some sorting, manipulating data, ...*.

#### Example

*The complete example uses `css selectors` instead of the `find()` / `find_all()` methods, cause in my opinion you can select more focused but result is the same.*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

base_url = 'http://www.warrencountyschools.org'
url = 'https://www.warrencountyschools.org/district_staff.aspx?action=search&location=29&department=0'
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)

fieldContent = []

for a in soup.select('a:-soup-contains("[Profile]")'):
    profilePagResp = http.request('GET', base_url+a['href'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(profilePagResp.data)

    keys = [x.text[:-1] for x in soup.select('.field-label')]
    profile = dict(tuple(zip(keys,[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('.field-content')])))

    if (website := soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Access Staff Website")')):
        profile['Website'] = base_url+website['href']
    else:
        profile['Website'] = ''

    fieldContent.append(profile)

pd.DataFrame(fieldContent).fillna('')[['Name','Email','Website','Phone','Buildings']]#.to_csv('profile.csv', index=False)
```

#### Output

| Name | Email | Website | Phone | Buildings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Greg Blewett | Greg.blewett@warren.kyschools.us | http://www.warrencountyschools.org/olc/13650 | 270-746-7205 | Greg Blewett - Construction-Carpentry - Warren County Area Technology Center |
| Adrian Boggess | adrian.boggess@warren.kyschools.us |  |  | Tike Barton - Computerized Manufacturing and Machining - Warren County Area Technology Center |
| Kim Coomer | kim.coomer@warren.kyschools.us |  | 270-746-7205 | Kim Coomer - Career Specialist - Warren County Area Technology Center |
| Rex Cundiff | Rex.cundiff@warren.kyschools.us | http://www.warrencountyschools.org/olc/13651 | 270-746-7205 | Rex Cundiff - Welding - Warren County Area Technology Center |